# Is it better to boot ubuntu in UEFI or in non-UEFI?

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, uefi, bios

I have a laptop with windows 8 installed in UEFI. I want to remove windows 8 completely and boot Ubuntu in it. Since i am going to use the laptop for embedded and robotics, how am i recommended to boot Ubuntu 14.04. whether in UEFI or non-UEFI.

Comment: It really does not matter much.

Answer (score 0):

The Unified Extensible Firmware Interface is a specification that defines a software interface between an operating system and platform firmware, meaning that it will not be bad to have, and I see no benefit of removing it. Keep it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, this link cleared it up for me, but let me know if yhou have any other questions since I just spent a lot of time researching that and made it work for me.

[When to use UEFI or BIOS for Ubuntu USB live or installation][1]

IT's nice and simply summarized, which I like.

Comment: @David  In this particular instance, since it sounds like an install on a laptop I would normally say UEFI because he doens't have to worry about whether it will work on other systems, etc.  UNLESS, possibly, some of the robotics stuff will be using older programs that need Bios/Legacy support in some way.  But either way, the article i posted hopefully will work.

Comment: You didn't give the URL of your link, and I can't find a article online with the same title.

Comment: I cant find the URL, it is just the text.